# How to handle large JSON response using $.getJSON method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a lot of data in a local JSON file and I can get that data successfully using jQuery's `$.getJSON` on every `keyup`.

But the response data is too large, about 10000 records out of 13,00,000, and it slows down all the page and sometime breaks the browser. I know there are lots of answers, but all are for Ajax response and server-side dependable.

What is the best way to handle large json response data which are get using `$.getJSON`?

here is what I have tried

1. I have try to break the response and show only 20 rows - but I need to show all data to user
2. use to show 20 rows and other rows on page scroll - but as I get data on every `keyup`, so this is not possible

jQuery code

```
$.getJSON(path + "abc.json", function(data){
    $('input').on('keyup', function(){
        var inputVal = $(this).val(),
        myExp = new RegExp(inputVal, "i"),
        sortedResultNames = [];

        if(inputVal.length >= 3){
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                if (value[searchTermsVal].search(new RegExp(inputVal,"i")) != -1) {
                    if( $(index).length < 20 ) {
                        sortedResultNames.push(value[searchTermsVal]);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        // get data after 20 rows from json response and append to the div
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you should return only top 20 or 50 most relevant data. See google maps, it only returns first data.

Comment: @RicardoPontual OP is saying they have a static file and not a serverside to chunk it.

Comment: Well first I would move `new RegExp(inputVal,"i")` outside so it is not being built on every iteration. No need to keep redefinging it when it is not changing. Second, loops are expensive so it will take awhile, but as the user types you can use array that you found on the previous so you are not always going over the full set. And you might want to look into a Web worker.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for helpful advice but how i retrieve data on scroll page

Comment: getJSON has nothing to do with this. That part happens up front, and is not causing the keyup to be slow. What's causing the keyup to be slow is looping over a huge array (not json) of data. what are you doing with `sortedResultNames`?

Comment: *"how i retrieve data on scroll page"* for starters... don't do it on every scroll event, that event happens a lot.

Comment: @KevinB i `append` the `sortedResultNames` in the html page for user

Comment: @KevinB so how i show all the records in minimum time